Differences in two compilers
I was testing a template available in Overleaf provided by PNAS (template here) and in Overleaf it compile succesfully, that is to say, three pages are compiled and second page is in two column format (see first image)

However, when I compile it (I downloaded full source from Overleaf) in TeXstudio, I get this:

The content below the "Data Archival" paragraph has dissapeared! Also in Overleaf there were three pages and in my editor there are two. I'm compiling with PdfLaTeX in the same way as Ovearleaf  but I don't understand why there are two different results. Just in case I will share the configuration I have for PdfLatex:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance :D

overleaf/texstudio make no difference what matters is the package versions used and which commands you run. overleaf uses latexmk which will run pdflatex and bibtex and pdflatex again as often as needed to resolve all cross references. Have you done that locally or just run pdflatex once?

Oh, you got reason, before I compiled two times but I didn't get results. Now I configure TeXstudio to compile as you described it and it worrked well. Thank you so much
